# How to change page sizing/format when load and existing template into JasperDesign and then changed it?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I am bringing this question from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772240/how-to-change-page-format-in-runtimejasperreport). I was not sure if I should create a new question since it seems I was already creating a new topic? Apologies upfront for that.

So here is my problem:

I am trying to dynamically change the format of my report (A book report, with several pages or parts or subreports). What I am doing is loading it first, from an existing template into a JasperDesign Object holder. Then, modifying the size an other parameters of the page itself. Later, I will compile and try to print a PDF format report with the compiled file. Ultimately, I want to print a hole book report with different pages and different templates for each individual pages with a format that I can specify.

Here is what I have done. I was able to point the main report to the other individual pages formats. So, when I export the report to PDF everything looks good(Like you probably imagine it was not that simple to get there. but now is working). So now I want to parametrize the format (A4, LETTER, etc.) on runtime for every single page of the Book Report.

Is this posible? I mean to do this dynamically instead of creating a new static template for each page and format and then creating a mantainence issue? If so which is the way of doing this?

Here is my code for retriving the JasperDesing Object template:

```
private static JasperDesign getTemplateDesign(String templatePath) throws JRException{

    JasperDesign design = JRXmlLoader.load(templatePath);

    logger.info("Setting Page Dimessions Format to: " + pageFormat);
    if(JRDriver.pageFormat.equals("A3")){
    JRDriver.pageWidth=842; 
    JRDriver.pageHeight=1190;
    JRDriver.columnCount=1;
    JRDriver.columnWidth=802;
    JRDriver.columnSpacing=0;
    JRDriver.leftMargin=20;
    JRDriver.rightMargin=20;
    JRDriver.topMargin=30;
    JRDriver.bottomMargin=30;
    }
    else if (JRDriver.pageFormat.equals("A4")) {
        JRDriver.pageWidth=842; 
        JRDriver.pageHeight=1190;
        JRDriver.columnCount=1;
        JRDriver.columnWidth=555;
        JRDriver.columnSpacing=0;
        JRDriver.leftMargin=20;
        JRDriver.rightMargin=20;
        JRDriver.topMargin=30;
        JRDriver.bottomMargin=30;
    }
    else if (JRDriver.pageFormat.equals("LETTER")) {            
        JRDriver.pageWidth=612; 
        JRDriver.pageHeight=792;
        JRDriver.columnCount=1;
        JRDriver.columnWidth=517;
        JRDriver.columnSpacing=0;
        JRDriver.leftMargin=20;
        JRDriver.rightMargin=20;
        JRDriver.topMargin=30;
        JRDriver.bottomMargin=30;
    }
    //Setting twmplate dimesions
    design.setPageWidth(JRDriver.pageWidth);
    design.setPageHeight(JRDriver.pageHeight);

    design.setColumnCount(JRDriver.columnCount);
    design.setColumnWidth(JRDriver.columnWidth);
    design.setColumnSpacing(JRDriver.columnSpacing);

    design.setLeftMargin(JRDriver.leftMargin);
    design.setRightMargin(JRDriver.rightMargin);
    design.setTopMargin(JRDriver.topMargin);
    design.setBottomMargin(JRDriver.bottomMargin);

    return design;
}
```

Here is my code fragment for generating the PDF report:

...

```
logger.info("Retrieving Design Template..." + reportTemplatePath);
    JasperDesign design= getTemplateDesign(reportTemplatePath);

    //jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportTemplatePath);
    jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(design);

    logger.info("Filling Report...");
    jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, jasperParameter,new JREmptyDataSource() );//new JREmptyDataSource()


    jasperPrint.setPageWidth(JRDriver.pageWidth);
    jasperPrint.setPageHeight(JRDriver.pageHeight);

    //Create the file dir
    File file = new File(reportOuputPath);
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    //file.delete();

    logger.info("Writing PDF..." + reportOuputPath);
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, reportOuputPath);
```

...

I could include the information for my JRXML static template files. But I don't think that is necessary for now. It can be done if you think otherwise

Please help me and thanks in advance

Comment: You have changed the page dimensions in the `JasperDesign`, but this does **not** automatically move and re-dimension all textFields, images etc. You need to go back to post and check what other solutions you can implement to achieve full page layout

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick comment. I do compile the new design before printing it, si don't know what else needs to be done. I also have try this from an static stand point (with different JRXML and different page format) and it does the magic. So I am not sure what you mean. Would you be more specific on what needs to be done. I can't post in the previous thread because is a different topic. Thanks

Comment: You need to use dynamic report or dynamic jasper... or different jrxml files  if you like fullpage layout. What I mean is that even if you change page size a textField will have same position as before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello and thanks for the quick answer. I couldn't find how to comment on you answer so I guess I will have to include it in this post.

First, you were right about not guaranteeing the whole page layout resizing, by just changing the de page dimensions. However, the formats that I was changing to, were very similar (A4 and LETTER), so the impact on the components and fields size perse, was not that big.

Moreover, what I have to do, to actually change every single individual's page of the book format, was loading every single individual page first into a JasperDesing Object holder and next save it , with the modified size into a jasper field, that will be used in the fillup process. Instead of just doing that for the Report Book page itself.

Here is the code:

```
    private static JasperDesign getPageTemplateDesign(String templatePath) throws JRException{

    logger.info("Setting format page desing for Template: " + templatePath);

    JasperDesign design = JRXmlLoader.load(templatePath);

    logger.info("Setting Page Dimessions Format to: " + pageFormat);
    if (JRDriver.pageFormat.equals("A4")) {
        JRDriver.pageWidth=595; 
        JRDriver.pageHeight=842;
        JRDriver.columnCount=1;
        JRDriver.columnWidth=555;
        JRDriver.columnSpacing=0;
        JRDriver.leftMargin=20;
        JRDriver.rightMargin=20;
        JRDriver.topMargin=20;
        JRDriver.bottomMargin=20;
    }
    else if (JRDriver.pageFormat.equals("LETTER")) {
        JRDriver.pageWidth=612; 
        JRDriver.pageHeight=792;
        JRDriver.columnCount=1;
        JRDriver.columnWidth=517;
        JRDriver.columnSpacing=0;
        JRDriver.leftMargin=20;
        JRDriver.rightMargin=20;
        JRDriver.topMargin=20;
        JRDriver.bottomMargin=20;
    }
    //Setting twmplate dimesions
    design.setPageWidth(JRDriver.pageWidth);
    design.setPageHeight(JRDriver.pageHeight);

    design.setColumnCount(JRDriver.columnCount);
    design.setColumnWidth(JRDriver.columnWidth);
    design.setColumnSpacing(JRDriver.columnSpacing);

    design.setLeftMargin(JRDriver.leftMargin);
    design.setRightMargin(JRDriver.rightMargin);
    design.setTopMargin(JRDriver.topMargin);
    design.setBottomMargin(JRDriver.bottomMargin);      

    return design;
}

private static void reformattingPageTemplate(String path) throws JRException{

    logger.info("Getting Design Template from: " + path);
    JasperDesign design= getPageTemplateDesign(path);

    String destFile=path.replaceAll("jrxml", "jasper");     
    logger.info("Compiling Re-formated Design Template to: " + destFile);
    JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(design, destFile); 
}

private static void formattingALLPage() throws JRException{

    reformattingPageTemplate(reportBookPagesDir + "/FrontCover.jrxml");
    reformattingPageTemplate(reportBookPagesDir + "/Copyright.jrxml");
    reformattingPageTemplate(reportBookPagesDir + "/TableOfContent.jrxml");
    reformattingPageTemplate(reportBookPagesDir + "/Summary.jrxml");
    reformattingPageTemplate(reportBookPagesDir + "/Content.jrxml");
    reformattingPageTemplate(reportBookPagesDir + "/AppendixWarnings.jrxml");
    reformattingPageTemplate(reportBookPagesDir + "/Index.jrxml");
    reformattingPageTemplate(reportBookPagesDir + "/BackCover.jrxml");
    //reformattingPageTemplate(reportTemplatePath);
}
```

Thanks for the help